# how to change text using style property in html, css

Tags: javascript, html, css

in this example, i have a button which has to change the text. Now I know that I can use the `onclick=document.getElementById('id').innerHTML="text"` but I am making a function such that

```
**onclick = myFunc()**


 <script>
    function myFunc()
    var x = document.getElementById('id');
    x.style.property = 'text';
    </script>
```

so my question is , is there any property I can use which will change the text

Comment: If you know you can use `innerHTML` why won't you use it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_innerhtml

Comment: You could use the `textContent` property rather than `innerHTML`, but there's no CSS property available to JavaScript that can change the text of an element. Although you could use the `content` CSS property on generated elements which, so far as I know, are read-only to JavaScript. And even then will only read the original string, not the computed value (in the event of using `attr()` or `counter()` to set the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set text using :

```
<script>
    function myFunc(){
      var x = document.getElementById('btntext');
      x.style.color = "green";
      x.style.fontSize = "large";
      x.value = "This is new TExt";
   }
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="btntext" value="This test"/>
<button onClick="myFunc()" name="send">change color</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. "Style" properties are for styling.  With a few very specific exceptions, they are only for changing the look of the content. Not changing the content itself.

There are other alternatives to innerHTML.  innerHTML is for adding HTML content to the element.

One alternative is `textContent`. Which adds plain text to the element.

```js
var x = document.getElementById('foo');
x.textContent = 'text';
```

```html
<button id="foo">Hello World</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Text has been changed!";
}
```

```html
<h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
```